# MVC Data access logic

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I know that many people have asked this question but I still don't have a clear understanding where should be the Data access layer in an MVC project. 
Here is what I do:

- I have my Web application and the data access layer in separate projects
- In my data access project I have only one class (which I have named "DB") that processes all requests to the database
- And when I need for example a list with all books I call **DB.GetAllBooks();** from my controller

Is this a good practice or I should have a separate class for books operations, user operations etc in my data access layer?

Comment: you can have generic methods implemented in a generic class. That's more reusable and easy to mainatain

Comment: This works when you are a single developer on the project. With many developers, this breaks. Also, with a large domain, you will have a huge file to manage and version. While it results in massive number of separate class files, separating classes into their own class files is usually a good idea. You'll be able to see which methods a class have in a second.

Comment: Thank you for the response. So now I work alone and it's not a very big project so I will stick with a single class. :)